# Detecting Overlapping Circles in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using the OpenCV library for Python to detect the circles in an image. As a test case, I'm using the following image:

bottom of can:

[image]

I've written the following code, which should display the image before detection, then display the image with the detected circles added:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('can.png')
image_rgb = image.copy()
image_copy = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
grayscaled_image = cv2.cvtColor(image_copy, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

cv2.imshow("confirm", grayscaled_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()


circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image_copy, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.3, 20, param1=60, param2=33, minRadius=10,maxRadius=28)


if circles is not None:
    print("FOUND CIRCLES")
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    print(circles)
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), r, (255, 0, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
    cv2.imshow("Test", image + image_rgb)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get this:resultant image

[image]

I feel that my problem lies in the usage of the `HoughCircles()` function. It's usage is:

`cv2.HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]])`

where `minDist` is a value greater than 0 that requires detected circles to be a certain distance from one another. With this requirement, it would be impossible for me to properly detect all of the circles on the bottom of the can, as the center of each circle is in the same place. Would contours be a solution? How can I convert contours to circles so that I may use the coordinates of their center points? What should I do to best detect the circle objects for each ring in the bottom of the can?

Comment: not part of your problem, but for the future: `image_copy = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)` should be `image_copy = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` instead I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Not all but a majority of the circles can be detected by adaptive thresholding the image, finding the contours and then fitting a minimum enclosing circle for contours having area greater than a threshold

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

block_size,constant_c ,min_cnt_area = 9,1,400
img = cv2.imread('viMmP.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,block_size,constant_c)
thresh_copy = thresh.copy()
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>min_cnt_area:
        (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
        center = (int(x),int(y))
        radius = int(radius)
        cv2.circle(img,center,radius,(255,0,0),1)
cv2.imshow("Thresholded Image",thresh_copy)
cv2.imshow("Image with circles",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Now this script yields the result:

[image]

[image]

But there are certain trade-offs like, if the `block_size` and `constant_c` are changed to 11 and 2 respectively then the script yields:

[image]

[image]

You should try applying erosion with a kernel of proper shape to separate the overlapping circles in the thresholded image

You may look at the following links to understand more about adaptive thresholding and contours:

Threshlding examples: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Thresholding reference: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html

Contour Examples:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: So if I simply cannot perfectly detect the exact size of each ring, is there a way to detect the image as a whole? Say, if I used my webcam and held up an image of the can, the program would detect specifically that image?

Comment: Yes,  you can convert the image to HSV and then threshold the image with a suitable threshold .  Apply closing operation (erosion + dilation) to the thresholded image to remove the unwanted noisy components appearing due to background.  Then find the external contours of this mask using RETR_EXTERNAL.  If there aren't noisy components present in the image  then you will get the outer circle.  Again you can use contour area to remove all the noisy components. If you want the can in  a black background then bitwise and the mask obtained after applying closing with the original BGR image.

Comment: I really appreciate the response, but I have no idea how to do any of that. I'm new to OpenCV and I can't seem to find a quality guide on how to use it. Would you recommend anything? How did you learn it?

Comment: There are many tutorials online.  The documentation itself is great and also there are examples inside the opencv folder.